# Why are we using three loops in Matrix Chain Multiplication?

Tags: algorithm, for-loop, matrix, dynamic-programming

I am studying Dynamic programming. I was stuck at this question Matrix Chain Multiplication. I understand the need of three loops. But how to come up with these arrangements like j = i+L-1 and test condition for i. 
There are some other DP questions with similar solutions and I have noticed that these loops are used to fill upper Triangle Matrix only. I want to know why we write loops like this ?

```
for (int L=2; L<n; L++){
    for (int i=1; i<n-L+1; i++)
    {
        int j = i+L-1; // Why ?
        m[i][j] = INT_MAX;
        for (int k=i; k<=j-1; k++)
        {
            int q = m[i][k] + m[k+1][j] + p[i-1]*p[k]*p[j];
            if (q < m[i][j])
            {
                m[i][j] = q;
            bracket[i][j] = k;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

L is the length of Chain.
i is for row number.
j is for column number.
k is the intermediate multiplication.